# Is a Galois group of a number field faithfully represented by its action on the set prime ideals of the ring of integers?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

Is a Galois group $G$ of a number field $K$ faithfully represented by its action on the set prime ideals of the ring of integers $O_K$?

This is true in some cases, like $Z[i]$. (Where we can see the group by its action on $(2 + i)$ and $(2 -i)$). I am wondering if it is true in general, or in some general class of cases.

In the monogenic case my best guess would be to find some integer $a$ so that $O_K = Z[a]$, and then try to find some prime $p \in Z$ which splits completely in $K$ into $(p, l(a))$ (for some linear $l$ by Kummer's theorem) and then analyze the action of $G$ on these ideals. Alternatively, one could try to lift the action of $G$ on the set of Galois conjugates $a_i$ to some ideals $(x + a_i)$, where $x$ is some integer that makes these ideals distinct somehow.

I'm not really sure what to do. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes. One way to see this is to note that there is a prime $p$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ which splits completely in $K$ (this is proved by analytic methods involving Dedekind zeta functions, and the Chebotarev Density Theorem implies the density of primes which split completely in $K$ is exactly $1/[K:\mathbb{Q}]$.) But the Galois group acts transitively on the primes of $K$ lying above $p$. There are exactly $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$ such primes, hence the action is faithful on the primes above $p$. This can even be generalized to Galois extensions of any number field, and the proof is the same.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to get a faithful representation even if we consider just the primes that ramify?

Comment: That is not always possible. For instance, consider $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)/\mathbb{Q}$, where $p$ is prime and $\zeta_p$ is a primitive $p$th root of unity. The only ramified prime is $p$, and it is totally ramified, so there is only one prime above it. This prime must then remain fixed under the action of the Galois group.